# Изменить стрелку select

Tags: javascript, css

мне нужно изменить стандартную стрелку select, что бы она была похожа на что-то такое. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Был бы благодарен за помощь.

```js
var month = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май','Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = i;
      option.text = month[i];
      monthList.appendChild(option);
  }

  
  for (var i = 1940; i < 2100; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = i;
      option.text = i;
      yearList.appendChild(option);
  }
```

```css
#monthList{
 border: 1px solid #CAD3D9;
 width: 128px;
 height: 28px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font:normal normal 14px 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
 padding-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 appearance: none;
}

#yearList{
 border: 1px solid #CAD3D9;
 width: 75px;
 height: 28px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font:normal normal 14px 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
#headDiv {
 border: 1px solid #E9EBED;
 width: 280px;
  background: #E9EBED;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 font:normal normal 14px 'Open Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
 box-shadow: 0 14px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }
```

```html
<div id = "headDiv"> 
    <select id = "monthList" onchange="changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value)"></select>
    <select id = "yearList"  onchange="changeTable(yearList.value, monthList.value)"></select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Средствами `css` можно убрать стандартную стрелку на основных браузерах и задать необходимую через `background`.

```css
*:focus{
  outline:none;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  padding:5px 30px 5px 10px;
  background: url(https://www.shareicon.net/download/2015/11/10/669927_arrows_512x512.png) no-repeat right 5px center / 11px auto;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>asd1</option>
  <option>asd2</option>
  <option>asd3</option>
</select>
```